# First Passage Time of Discrete Inhomogeneous Poisson Process

Tags: poisson-distribution, stopping-times, poisson-process

Consider the discrete time stochastic process $m_j=\sum_{i=1}^jx_i$ for a finite time interval $j=1,\dots,n$, where the increments $x_i\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda_i)$ are all independent Poisson random variates with respective parameters $\lambda_i>0$. Therefore for every fixed $j$:
$$
m_j\sim\text{Pois}(\Lambda_j),\quad\Lambda_j=\sum_{i=1}^j\lambda_i
$$

Now define the first passage time to level $s$ as
$$
\tau_s=\min\{j\in \{1,2,\dots,n,\infty\}\,:\,m_j\ge s\},\quad s=0,1,2,\dots
$$
where, as usual, $\infty$ is included to cover the case when the process $m_j$ does not reach level $s$ until time $n$.

- Is it possible to derive the distribution of $\tau_s$ in closed form?
- If yes, how?

Comment: have you tried using $\mathbb{P}(\tau_s \le t) = \mathbb{P}(\max_{k \le t} m_k \ge s)$?

Comment: @qervert Not yet, very interesting suggestion. $m_k$ is a non-decreasing process as the increments are non-negative integers, so $\max_{k\le j}m_k=m_j$, which is Poisson, and then the right hand side is just $1-\Gamma(s,\Lambda_j)/\Gamma(s)$. So this would be $\mathbb{P}(\tau_s\le j)$, the CDF? Too simple to be true, honestly

Answer (score 1):

Using @qervert's great suggestion I am answering my own question:

For $s=0$ the definition implies $\tau_0=1$ on all paths of $m_j$. Hence $\mathbb{P}(\tau_0=j)=\delta_{j,1}$, where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker symbol, and the CDF is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_0\le j)=1,\quad j=1,\dots,n,\infty.\tag{1}
$$

For $s\ge1$ the suggestion in the comment works and the CDF for finite times is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_s\le j)=1-\frac{\Gamma(s,\Lambda_j)}{\Gamma(s)},\quad j=1,\dots,n,\tag{2a}
$$
and we have a finite probability of not reaching level $s$ until time $n$ given by
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_s=\infty)=\frac{\Gamma(s,\Lambda_n)}{\Gamma(s)},\tag{2b}
$$
which is the missing weight needed to make a proper CDF, $\mathbb{P}(\tau_s\le\infty)=1$.